# Controller-based Associations/Relations in SailsJS

Tags: node.js, rest, sails.js

Say I have a `ShoppingCart` model with a one-to-many relation to an `Item` model (i.e. A shopping cart can be full of different items).

I can obviously create a new shopping cart like so:

```
POST /api/shoppingcart
```

What I'd like to create is a RESTful API where an item can be added (or updated) to that shopping cart like this:

```
POST /api/shoppingcart/:shoppingCartId/item
PUT /api/shoppingcart/:shoppingCartId/item/:itemId
```

From the research I've done so far this doesn't seem built-in to SailsJS. I'd prefer to stay away from manually setting these routes. Is there a way I can automate the route with the `ShoppingCartController`?

Comment: So you're saying you want both your POST and PUT to go to the same controller method, even though their signature is different?

Comment: Nope, I'm asking how to hook up a relational route. Sails binds certain routes automatically if you have RESTful routes option enabled. I'm wondering if that can be extended to models that have associations with other models.

Comment: Still not entirely sure what you're asking for... From reading the documentation, it sounds like you set up your route and point it to the proper controller's method.  So `'POST /api/shoppingcart/:shoppingCartId/item': 'ShoppingCartController.AddToShoppingCart'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, found out Sails does it as long as you have the config `rest` option enabled.

It works with `GET`, `POST`, and `DELETE` methods.

```
[parentModel]/:parentid/[childModel]/:id?
```

Check the source: https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/blob/master/lib/hooks/blueprints/index.js#L319